# Rails - Programmatically get templates before they are compiled and rendered.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a use case in which I would like to have access to all my templates as they are, meaning html + erb (or any other template handler) and do something with them before they are compiled (in my case I want to check for the existence of a hardcoded strings). Is there a way in the Rails API to hook into this?

Comment: At what time do you want to do that check? While starting the Rails server or at every HTTP request?

Comment: It does not matter actually. Ideally I want to this on command, so on a rake task or through a test. Something like MyChecker.check! that I can call when I need it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK rails resolves path-names lazily, so there is no point where you would have "all paths". new paths can be added to the lookup at any point, so your application logic would have to make sure to keep in sync with that.

i think that you can achieve whatever you want to do by creating your own template resolver and apply whatever transformation lazily as well. have a look at `actionview/lib/action_view/template/resolver.rb` and it's implementations.

the book [crafting rails applications](https://pragprog.com/book/jvrails/crafting-rails-applications) has an excelent description of the rendering process and might help you find another solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you phoet. I'll take a look at that book (we have  a copy at work) and see what I can come up with.